# ForeignKey error on composite PK model class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've read ten post around this issue but still cannot understand what I am failing: I am stuck on this since two days.

ASPNET MVC5 web app. Code First

Models:

```
 public partial class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ISO_Languages
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public string name_en { get; set; }
    public string name_fr { get; set; }
    public string name_it { get; set; }
    public string name_de { get; set; }
    public string name_es { get; set; }
}

 public class CategoryTrans
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int language_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

CategoryTrans has a composite PK based on two FK: Category ID and ISO_Languages ID

I am just trying to correctly reference this architecture in CategoryTrans model, that is something like:

```
 public class CategoryTrans
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int language_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public virtual Category ID{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public virtual ISO_Languages ID2{ get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
```

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ID' on type 'xyz.Models.CategoryTrans' is not valid. The foreign key name 'ID' was not found on the dependent type 'xyz.Models.CategoryTrans'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names

```
    public class CategoryTrans
   {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int category_id { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int language_id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        public virtual Category catid{ get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ISO_Languages")]
        public virtual ISO_Languages languguageid{ get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
```

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'catid' on type 'xyz.Models.CategoryTrans' is not valid. The foreign key name 'Category' was not found on the dependent type 'xyz.Models.CategoryTrans'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Am I trying to do something impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 public partial class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryTrans> CategoryTrans { get; set; }
}

public class ISO_Languages
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public string name_en { get; set; }
    public string name_fr { get; set; }
    public string name_it { get; set; }
    public string name_de { get; set; }
    public string name_es { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryTrans> CategoryTrans { get; set; }
}
 public class CategoryTrans
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int language_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("category_id")]
    public virtual Category ID{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("language_id")]
    public virtual ISO_Languages ID2{ get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```